# Set out parameter value in exception block

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I am running the below mentioned function in PostgreSQL **migrated from Oracle( Procedure)**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_get_attachments
(
    OUT op_user_data refcursor
    ,OUT op_error_code text
    ,OUT op_error_desc text
)
returns  record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
 v_error_code varchar(10) := '0';
 begin
  OPEN op_user_data
   FOR
    SELECT file_complete_name, article_ref_id, file_name, file_path, content,file_extension
    FROM TBL_ATTACHMENT_MIG;
RAISE EXCEPTION 'excp_action' USING ERRCODE = '50001';

EXCEPTION
 WHEN SQLSTATE '50001' then
    op_error_code := v_error_code;
    op_error_desc := 
fn_error_detail(op_error_code,'PKG_MIGRATION_EGAIN','PROC_GET_ATTACHMENTS');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   op_error_code := v_error_code;
   op_error_desc := fn_error_detail(op_error_code,'PKG_MIGRATION_EGAIN','PROC_GET_ATTACHMENTS');

  END;
  $$
 ;
```

**fn_error_detail** is a common function which get data from  global error message table according to code and other parameters.

On executing the function using the command: `select * from proc_get_attachments();`

Getting the Output:

```
op_user_data      |op_error_code|op_error_desc                   |
------------------|-------------|--------------------------------|
<unnamed portal 1>|0            |Attachments fetched successfully|
```

Then on running command: `fetch all in "<unnamed portal 1>"`;

```
Error returned is : SQL Error [34000]: ERROR: cursor "" does not exist
```

Problem is that : cursor is not returning the data  but text output are properly displayed

Answer (score 0):

If there is an exception in a PL/pgSQL block, everything since the `BEGIN` that opened the block is rolled back.

Consequently the cursor is not bound — the `OPEN` was undone.

Comment: Are you saying that we need to open the cursor in the exception block also? Or what is the problem.

Comment: In the output it is giving `<unnamed portal 1>` against the cursor.

Comment: Yes, you would have to open the cursor in the exception block.

Comment: Is there any better way of doing the above. Basically we need to set a variable at different places depending on some condition and then go to exception and select the message form Table accordingly. But don't want to rollback the changes done earlier. We are managing the transaction form the C#.net.

Comment: It's hard to help, as the example is obviously artificial. Make smaller `BEGIN`/`EXCEPTION`/`END` blocks so that you don't lose anything important if you get an exception.